# Overriding Caching defined in Global ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cache-control, action-filter

my aim is to have a global `NoCacheActionFilter` attribute (registered in the `Global.asax.cs` ) which disables caching by default.

Then I'd like to add more fine-grained control in that on the needed Actions of my controllers I'd like to add a **caching** attribute which should override the one defined in the global `NoCacheActionFilter`.

**My Approach**

in the `NoCacheActionFilter`

```
public override void OnActionExcecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //disable caching
    HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    ...
}
```

and in the *caching attribute* ...

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    //add caching
    ...
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    ...
}
```

Note the difference between `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`, they should be invoked one after the other, so the order should be granted.

**However**, apparently this **does not** work. Any suggestions?? I have the feeling to miss some trivial thing...

Comment: The only way I managed to get something similar working, is by first invoking the private method `HttpCachePolicy.Reset()` [by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28445308)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. After changing the `Cache` object of the `filterContext` do you call the method of the base filter class?

```
    ...
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

and

```
    ...
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Nope...unfortunately adding it didn't change the behavior...still the global cache isn't being overridden. Is there maybe a constraint that global action filters always win over those declared specifically on controller actions?? (Although that would be really awkward)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the order the filters are running in are not what you expect.

Check out this blog post which explains the order they will run in:
http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2011/05/14/MVC3-Filter-Ordering.aspx